# Laravel Sanctum - Error status 404 o CORS

Tags: laravel, api

Buenas tengo problemas de CORS y de peticiones con respuesta 404, para logearme y registrame me funciona correctamente mas sin embargo cuando añado nueva ruta en la api, me sale problema de cors o de peticion, les adjunto el codigo de mis archivos de cors, api, peticion en vue y la configuracion del kernel. Si modifico el search en el archivo cors obtengo error de acceso. ¿Que hacer en este caso? o ¿que tengo mal?, login y el registro me funciona correctamente :(
Kernel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
   
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
}
```

cors.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        '*',
        'register',
        'country',
        'search',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie',

    ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:8080'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ['*'],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => TRUE,

];
```

Route/api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('countries', [App\Http\Controllers\CountryController::class, 'show']);
Route::post('login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('register',  [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'create']);

Route::post('search/{value}', [App\Http\Controllers\SearchPersonController::class, 'searchPerson'])->name('search');
```

Vuejs method

```
    async searchPerson(event){
      this.search = event.target.value
      await this.$http.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
       let searchUser = await this.$http.post(`search/${this.search}`,this.search)
      
     
      console.log(searchUser.json())
    }
```

Controller SearchPerson

```
class SearchPersonController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function searchPerson(Request $request){
        return var_dump($request);
    }   
}
```

Error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo primero que probaría es con el comando `php artisan route:clear`, por si tienes cacheadas las rutas. Y algo que posiblemente no tenga que ver, pero ya que estamos te comento, es que en el archivo *cors.php*,bajo la llave paths, `'api/*'` incluye todas las rutas del archivo *api.php*, así que no tendrías que agregar una por una.

Comment: gracias pero sigue igual.

Comment: Por lo que se ve en la imagen, la url que te devuelve el 404 está en `localhost:8000`, pero en la configuración de cors tienes `'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:8080'],`. ¿El backend está en el dominio `localhost:8000` y el frontend en `localhost:8080`?

Comment: el frontend localhost:8080 backend 8000, configure el axios para que las peticiones sean al localhost 8000

Comment: como mencione en el login y registro me funciona mas sin embargo creo otro controlador con la ruta del api y me sale eso que estare haciendo mal ?

Comment: ¿Qué te devuelve el comando `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: me sale error el controllador forgotpassword target class doesnt exist...

Comment: me sale esto:   | POST     | api/search/{value}     | search           | App\Http\Controllers\SearchPersonController@searchPerson               | Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful |

Comment: Revisa en el archivo *config/sanctum.php* que tienes en la clave `'stateful'`. Si es algo así `env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', 'localhost,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1'))`, revisa en el archivo *.env* que tienes en la clave `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS`.

Comment: no listo, era porque tenia que aplicar el api en la ruta del fetch